# Problems with context in js

Tags: javascript

I have decided to exercise in js and code call function. Nevertheless, I got stuck with `"undefined undefined"` output.
Here is the code:

```js
var alex = {
  name: "alex",
  surname: "surname",
}
let nameyourself = function() {
  console.log(`${this.name} ${this.surname}`);
}


Function.prototype.calling = function(smth) {
  smth.__proto__.calledfunct = this;
  return smth.__proto__.calledfunct();
}
nameyourself.calling(alex);
```

But when I delete `.__proto__`, everything works fine. I suppose that the function doesn't get the context of `alex`.

Comment: Where did you get `calledfunct` from? Is this a name you chose, or something you expected to have special meaning? Besides, you could, without manipulating the prototype, simply use: [`nameyourself.call(alex)`](https://jsfiddle.net/dwye1tu9/) - Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: I wanted to try without call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, that's because it doesn't get the right context.

Let's inspect:

When you do this:

```js
nameyourself.calling(alex)
```

...`smth` gets the value of `alex`, i.e. `{name:"alex", surname:"surname",}`.

`smth`'s `[[Prototype]]` (the internal property represented by `__proto__`) is `Object.prototype`, as `smth` is a plain object.

So this line:

```js
smth.__proto__.calledfunct=this
```

...is essentially equal to:

```js
Object.prototype.calledfunct=this
```

Then, you call it like this (for the same reason as above):

```js
Object.prototype.calledfunct()
```

Since the context will be the object whose property is called in case of a method call,  `nameyourself` is called with the context `Object.prototype`.

You get `undefined` twice because `Object.prototype` has neither `name` nor `surname` properties.

Test it yourself:

```js
var alex = {
  name: "alex",
  surname: "surname",
}
let nameyourself = function() {
  console.log('Object.prototype === this',Object.prototype === this) //true
  
  console.log(`${this.name} ${this.surname}`);
}


Function.prototype.calling = function(smth) {
  console.log('smth', smth)
  console.log('smth.__proto__', smth.__proto__)
  console.log('smth.__proto__ === Object.prototype', smth.__proto__ === Object.prototype) //true
  
  smth.__proto__.calledfunct = this;
  
  console.log('smth.__proto__.calledfunct', smth.__proto__.calledfunct)
  console.log('Object.prototype.calledfunct', Object.prototype.calledfunct)
  console.log('smth.__proto__.calledfunct === Object.prototype.calledfunct', smth.__proto__.calledfunct === Object.prototype.calledfunct) //true
  
  return smth.__proto__.calledfunct();
}
nameyourself.calling(alex);
```

**Side notes on this solution:**

Although this code works (without `.__proto__`s at least), contains multiple bad practices. It's OK for testing, but the use of this code in production is a bad idea.

Problems:

- Defining prototype methods without making them non-`enumerable`: define them with `Object.defineProperty` instead
- Extending a native prototype: subclass it instead
- Patching properties in a function call without reverting changes: use the built-in `Function#call` or `Function#apply` methods instead

Answer (score 0):

That is how I fixed it:

```
var alex={
     name:"alex",
     surname:"surname",
 }
 let nameyourself = function(){
     console.log(`${this.name} ${this.surname}`);
 }


 Function.prototype.calling=function(smth){
     console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(smth));
     smth.__proto__.calledfunct=this;
     return smth.calledfunct();
 }
 nameyourself.calling(alex);
```